# Ignoring signal hangup in pexpect 2.3

Tags: python, linux, cloud, signals, pexpect

I am using python 2.6.6 with pexpect 2.3

I  execute a script in a remote server using pexpect using following approach.

```
def doSsh(user,password,host,command):
    try:
        child =  pexpect.spawn("ssh  -o ServerAliveInterval=100 -n %s@%s '%s'" % (user,host,command), logfile=sys.stdout, ignore_sighup=True, timeout=None)
        i = child.expect(['password:', r'\(yes\/no\)',r'.*password for paasusr: ',r'.*[$#] ',pexpect.EOF])
        if i == 0:
                child.sendline(password)
        elif i == 1:
                child.sendline("yes")
                child.expect("password:")
                child.sendline(password)
        data = child.read()
        print data
        child.close()
        return True
    except Exception as error:
        print error
        return False
```

And I call it :

```
doSsh(vmUser,vmPasswd,vmName,'cd '+OutputDir+';python cvm-bringup.py setup')
```

The problem is this execution takes `~6` hours to complete. So 95% of the time  SIGHUP is received from the child and the parent script dies without going further.

Is there any way to ignore SIGHUP here ?

I tried putting the option `ignore_sighup=True` inside spawn. But it didn't work and threw error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_sighup'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1- `SIGHUP` signal is ignored by default before [`pexpect 4.0`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/history.html#version-4-0). Though it is about `SIGHUP` received by `ssh` (locally).  2- It is unlikely that `child.read()` is expected to work for 6 hours (either too little output (timeout between read bytes) or too much (the output might be limited by a buffer size ~1e6))

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, thanks. But what do you suggest ?